# Automatically download a list of images and name them

Tags: windows, excel, vba, download

I have a xls/csv list of images:

```
Name        image url
test.jpg    http://test.com/232dd.jpg
test2.jpg   http://test.com/2390j.jpg
```

I have about 200 of these...is there a way to download the list and name them as identified in the xls file?

Here is my Excel VBA:

```
Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
    Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, _
    ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, _
    ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

Private Sub download_pics()
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim cell As Variant

  Set rng = Range("A1:B10")
  For Each cell In rng
    ' Download the file.
    URLDownloadToFile 0, cell(rng, 2).Value, "C:\" & cell(rng, 1).Value, 0, 0
  Next
End Sub
```

Running into type mismatch error with URLDownloadToFile

Comment: [Yes, this is possible](http://bit.ly/1eD03M6).  If you have a specific problem implementing code, please provide what code you have tried, how it is failing, and what are the desired results.

Comment: I just tried this:  Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
    Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, _
    ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, _
    ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long
    
    
Private Sub download_pics()

Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Variant
 
Set rng = Range("A1:B10")

For Each cell In rng
    ' Download the file.
    URLDownloadToFile 0, _
        cell(rng, 2).Value, _
        "C:\" & cell(rng, 1).Value, 0, 0


        Next
End Sub

Comment: I'll take a look. I don't think you need to use the WinAPI to download files, let me see if I have another method you can use.

Comment: Have you had a chance to try the code I suggested??

Answer (score 0):

OK The type mismatch has to do with your iteration.  You need to specify how you're iterating over `rng` with the `For each cell in rng` statement, like:

`For each cell in rng.Rows`

Otherwise, it treats that statement as `For each cell in rng.Cells` and that raises the mismatch error.

I made some modifications to the code (based on Sid's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383614/get-pictures-from-a-url-and-then-rename-the-picture)), so it checks to ensure the file downloaded successfully, but mostly what you found was correct, you just need to implement it a little differently.

```
Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
    Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, _
    ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, _
    ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

Private Sub download_pics()
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim myRow As Range
  Dim imgName As String
  Dim fileLocation As String
  Dim Ret As Long 'return value from the URLDownloadToFile function
  Set rng = Range("A1:B10")
  For Each myRow In rng.Rows
    With myRow
        imgName = .Columns(2).Value
        fileLocation = "C:\" & .Columns(1).Value
        With .Columns(1).Offset(, 2)
            If URLDownloadToFile(0, imgName, fileLocation, 0, 0) = 0 Then
                .Value = "downloaded successfully"
            Else:
                .Value = "download failed!"
            End If
        End With
    End With
  Next
End Sub
```