# VBA url download and renaming is unsuccessful

Tags: vba, url, download, rename

Using VBA, I am trying to download images from url, renaming them and saving them to folder. 
I have found code that facilitates this, but it seems that all "names" with a "/" in it won't download.

Is this possible? Is there a way around it?

I have tried the code from the link [Downloading Images from URL and Renaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42184990/downloading-images-from-url-and-renaming)

No error messages are provided. The images simply won't download.

Answer (score 0):

Files are not allowed to have a / in their name, that's always been the case. The code works unless you put a symbol that's not allowed, which are `/ \ : * ? " < > |`